# Ajex File Manager для CKEditor'a не хочет создавать папки

Tags: php, ckeditor

Пытаюсь приклеить к `CKEditor` файловый менеджер [`Ajex File Manager`](http://www.demphest.ru/ru/programming/ajex-filemanager/).
Проблема возникает на этапе создания папок (запуска `ajax.php?isWork`).
При запуске `php`-файла с гет-параметром белая страница и ничего нет.
Пытаюсь сделать это всё на денвере. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: ошибки в php включите или смотрите в логе.

Comment: а как ошибки в PHP включить?

Comment: Они вроде бы и так включены.

Comment: Смотрите [error_reporting][1]

   [1]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Я правильно понял, что в самом начале файла нужно прописать error_reporting(E_ALL); ? Если так, то всё равно ничего не выводится.

Comment: И в логе глянул. Никаких ошибок касаемо файлового менеджера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина: открывать `connector` недопустимо без самого `js` файлового менеджера. Нет не скажу что невозможно но есть же определенная степень защиты там скажем сессии, спец запросы. Чтобы понять что происходит рекомендую использовать `google chrome` в нем есть инструмент для отслеживания всего, что происходит. Открыть его можно правой кнопкой мыши на странице которая интересует и выбрав пункт "проверить элемент" или просто нажав `F12`. Дальше больше... Переходите на вкладку `Console` и смотрите нет ли ошибок. Если есть исправляете. Далее опять же обновляетесь проверяете ошибки и переходите на вкладку `Network` там загруженные страницы и файлы. Вот здесь и будет самое интересное. Нажимаете создать папку. При этом сайт пошлет запрос. Следсвенно и получит ответ. т.е. появится новый файл во вкладке `Network` смотрим на заголовки, ответы... Анализируем и определяемся с действиями. Если нет вариантов - пишем сюда.

Comment: Да я как бы верю что все нормально. Может не хватает прав на запись в папку или еще что. Так я вам написал где посмотреть ответы.

Comment: Во вкладке консоль никаких ошибок не появляется. Во вкладке нэтворк файл ajax.php. Непонятно, что где исправлять?

Comment: cудя с настроек этого файла понятно:
1. нужно чтобы были созданы папки 
upload,
upload/_thumb,upload/file,upload/flash, upload/image... !ajax.php в принципе сам должен создать эти папки и скорее всего прав нет на их создание скажем установлена опция open_basedir
 
2. Нужно чтобы в php были включены расширения:
gd2, mbstring.
И этот файл проверяет доступность функций:
json_encode,mb_internal_encoding,mb_substr,mb_ereg_replace,mb_strlen,
imagecreatetruecolor,imagefill,imagecopyresampled,imagejpeg,imagedestroy.
Следовательно надо это все проверить на работоспособность.

Comment: Знать бы ещё, как это делается.

Comment: На хостинге всё работает. А как сделать, чтобы создавалась только папка images?